# "не обращать внимания" - когда В.п, а когда Р.п

Tags: родительный-или-винительный

В интернете написано, что правильно писать - "не обращать внимания", обосновывая тем, что должен стоять родительный падеж. У меня вопрос: можно ли ставить в В.п., и если да, то при каких условиях? А если подобное словосочетание всегда должно быть в Р.п. (не обращать внимания, не обращай внимания, не обратил внимания и другие формы), то почему?

И вообще есть ли какие-то общие правила для понимания, ставится Р.п. или В.п.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иногда такое возможно, например, в случае противопоставления словосочетания "обращать внимание" какому-либо действию:

> Вам нужно сосредоточиться на содержании лекции, **а** *не обращать внимание*
> на внешность докладчицы.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, тут всё просто. Если отрицание-то Р.п, если форма утвердительная-то В.п. Только конструкция должна быть независима от других грамматических основ.

Вам нужно СОСРЕДОТОЧИТЬСЯ на содержании лекции, а не ОБРАЩАТЬ внимание на внешность докладчицы.

Или:

Вам нужно СОСРЕДОТОЧИТЬСЯ на содержании лекции, и НЕ ОБРАЩАТЬ ВНИМАНИЯ на внешность докладчицы.